# How do I tell DOMDocument->load() what encoding I want it to use?

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I search for and process XML files from elsewhere, and need to
transform them with some XSLTs. No problem. Using PHP5 and the DOM
library, everything's a snap. Worked fine, up till now. Today, funky
characters were in the XML file -- "smart" quotes from Word, it looks
like. Anyways, DOMDocument->load complained about them, saying that
they weren't UTF-8, and to specify the encoding.

Lo and behold, the encoding is not specified in these XML files. If I
add in 'encoding="iso-8859-1"' to the header, it works fine. The rub is
I have no control over these XML files.

Reading the file into a string, modifying its header and writing it back
out to another location seems to be my only option, but I'd prefer to do
it without having to use temporary copies of the XML files at all. Is
there any way to simply tell the parser to parse them as if they were
iso-8859-1?

Answer (score 10):

Does this work for you?

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
$doc->load($xmlPath);
```

**Edit:** Since it appears that this doesn't work, what you could do instead is similar to your existing method but without the temp file. Read the XML file from your source just using standard IO operations (`file_get_contents()` or something), then perform whatever changes to the encoding you need (`iconv()` or `utf8_decode()`)  and then use `loadXML()`

```
$myXMLString = file_get_contents($xmlPath);
$myXMLString = utf8_decode($myXMLString);
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
$doc->loadXML($myXMLString);
```

Comment: Tried this - it does not seem to effect the loaded document - from my reading, I'm pretty sure the encoding gets reset by the load() call

Answer (score 5):

I haven't found a way to set the default encoding (yet) but **maybe** the recover mode is feasible in this case.
When libxml encounters an encoding error and no encoding has been explicitly set it switches from unicode/utf8 to latin1 and continues parsing the document. But in the parser context the property `wellFormed` is set to 0/false. PHP's DOM extension considers the document valid if `wellFormed` is true **or** the DOMDocument object's attribute [`recover`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.recover) is true.

```
<?php
// german Umlaut ä in latin1 = 0xE4
$xml = '<foo>'.chr(0xE4).'</foo>';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$b = $doc->loadxml($xml);
echo 'with doc->recover=false(default) : ', ($b) ? 'success':'failed', "\n";

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->recover = true;
$b = $doc->loadxml($xml);
echo 'with doc->recover=true : ', ($b) ? 'success':'failed', "\n";
```

prints

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xE4 0x3C 0x2F 0x66 in Entity, line: 1 in test.php on line 6
with doc->recover=false(default) : failed

Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xE4 0x3C 0x2F 0x66 in Entity, line: 1 in  test.php on line 11
with doc->recover=true : success
```

You still get the warning message (which can be suppressed with @$doc->load()) and it will also show up in the [internal libxml errors](http://php.net/libxml_use_internal_errors) (only once when the parser switches from utf8 to latin1). The error code for this particular error will be 9 (XML_ERR_INVALID_CHAR).

```
<?php
$xml = sprintf('<foo>
    <ae>%s</ae>
    <oe>%s</oe>
    &
</foo>', chr(0xE4),chr(0xF6));

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->recover = true;
libxml_clear_errors();
$b = $doc->loadxml($xml);
$invalidCharFound = false;
foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
    if ( 9==$error->code && !$invalidCharFound ) {
        $invalidCharFound = true;
        echo "found invalid char, possibly harmless\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "hm, that's probably more severe: ", $error->message, "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The ony way to specify the encoding is in the XML declaration at the start of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly